# VBA: PowerPoint and Excel integration BOOKS

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Google (which usually refers to here ;-) ) helps tremendously when trying to learn "how to create/modify PowerPoint slides with Excel".

But now: From where do you guys know all this stuff? Is there a book wich teaches you this? I have tons of usual VBA Books - and know VBA quite well, but don't really get the PowerPoint stuff. My boss put me on a project which requires me to modify existing PowerPoint slides with Excel, so a book would be quite usful...

Comment: Before this gets closed as off topic.. I have actually gotten use out of MS's [object reference for PPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743835.aspx) (found via Google). An initial understanding of VBA applied to Excel was enough to start transferring knowledge to the PPT object model. Unfortunately, MS, in their infinite wisdom, decided that PPT doesn't need a macro recorder, so it does take some additional digging.

Comment: yes, the missing macro recorder is a Problem... Thank's anyway! Was hoping there was a book or something... Searche for hours for an appropriate book.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few PowerPoint VBA examples and links to other sites with examples in the Programming section of my PPT FAQ site (http://www.pptfaq.com)  Most of the examples you find will be written to run from within PPT itself, but it's generally a simple matter to modify them to work from within Excel, Access, a VB program, etc.

If you're not all that familiar with PowerPoint, get familiar with it; learning how to do things "manually" will give you a better grasp of how PowerPoint "thinks" about the world, and will make it far easier for you to do things with it programmatically.

The VB IDE in PowerPoint offers some help; most of it is pretty sad, but there are a few nuggets of Goodness to be found.  And in the IDE, press F2 and explore the Object Browser to learn what events, methods and properties are there for you to work with.